# find matching values in columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare the columns of two df's

condition = if values of df1 in df 2 -> do somehting

I used `np.where` but this method as i understood it correctly only compares values with same row index
so

```
df_main['matching'] = np.where(df_main['Surname'] == df_third['Name'], 'True', 'False')
```

does not work for my case

I tested a standard loop comparison

```
for i in df_main['Nachname']:
    if i == df_third['Name']:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

this returned a `ValueError: Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`
and after testing this methods I coud not find a use for them.

there is definitely a method for that case, but i could not find it so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html?highlight=isin#pandas.DataFrame.isin)

```
df_main['matching'] = df_main['Surname'].isin(df_third['Name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace '==' by 'in' in your second line. Let me know if it works

```
for i in df_main['Nachname']:
    if i in df_third['Name']:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that already but does not work, it gives me always "false" as a return

Comment: Strange. Are you sure that there is at least one common element between these 2 columns? Check the type of the data as well (eg string instead of numeric) or values with spaces